# -webkit BLUR NOT WORKING phonegap 3.3

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, webkit, phonegap-build

Hy... I'm try'ing to create a blur effect on a image in phonegap 3.3 on android and it doesn't appear the blur effect at all, it displays only the picture... It works on ripple emulator just fine but on the phone it doesn't.

This is my code:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(30px);
    -moz-filter: blur(30px);
    -o-filter: blur(30px);
    -ms-filter: blur(30px);
    filter: blur(30px);

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
```

Is it not supported on phonegap 3.3 on android? If not what else should I try yo achive my desired effect? Are there other workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: did u get any solution for these issue? m facing same problem..

Comment: @Navneeth no man. I ended up uring blur.js

Answer (score 0):

looks like CSS filters are only supported in Android Browsers 4.4 and up, not sure what phone gap 3.3 is using to render, but you can see a full compatibility chart here http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20filter

Comment: So I guess the filters are not compatible yet if it ain't working... But can someone please suggest me an alternative if it exists to blur an image using css jquery and jquery mobile?

Comment: Does anibody know another solution to this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://blurjs.com/?bg=3&fixed
All it needs support for is canvas

Comment: Is it not also using webkit filter?

Comment: Anyone please? I;m searching for days! please!!